# The limit as x approaches to infinity where c is a constant

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't figure out the limit of

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}1-\left (1-\left(\frac{c}{x}\right)^x \right)$$

as x approaches to infinity. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Did you mean $$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \bigg(1-(1-\frac{c}{x})^x \bigg)$$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (c/x)^x = 0$$
So your limit becomes 0.

If you meant this instead:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} 1-(1-\frac{c}{x})^x$$
Then it is
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} 1-((1-\frac{c}{x})^{\frac{x}{-c}})^{-c}$$
$$=1-e^{-c}$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

The limit indicated in the OP is well defined for $c\ge 0$, and it suffices to prove that

$$\left(\frac c x \right)^x\to 0$$

indeed for $x>2c \implies \frac c x<\frac12$ and

$$0\le \left(\frac c x \right)^x\le \left(\frac12 \right)^x \to 0$$

For the following

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} 1-\left(1-\frac{c}{x}\right)^x$$

we have

$$\left[\left(1-\frac{c}{x}\right)^\frac{x}{c}\right]^c\to e^{-c}$$